# Does every player need the "Gates of Midgard Challenge Pack" in multiplayer?

Tags: magicka-2

When I buy the challenge pack, will my fellow players in a multiplayer game also need the DLC in order to join my game on those maps? Or is it sufficient if I (as the host) buy the DLC?